# How to make a giant matrix in C

Tags: c, matrix

I'm trying to define a matrix in C with 100,000 columns and 100,000 lines of boolean type (bool matrix[100000][100000]), how I do that?

Comment: `static bool matix[100000][100000];`

Comment: And you intend to use every element?

Comment: How much memory do you have?

Comment: Note that this will take more than a GB of memory

Comment: Assuming one byte per `bool`, this will occupy around 9.3 GB of memory, which is quite a lot. You can't expect to put that much data on the stack (where `auto` variables typically live), which is why `static` helps.

Comment: @aochagavia That's true, but not very precise. :)

Comment: We'd really need to know *why*. Something that big could have performance issues as well as pure storage problems.

Comment: one `byte` per `bool` is madness. You have (usually) 8 `bits` per-`byte` which allows for 8 booleans in one single `byte`.

Comment: Many applications that use such large data structures typically only use a fraction of the elements, with the rest remaining set to zero.  If this is the case for you, I strongly recommend you look into [sparse matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) techniques.

Comment: Brute force, use a machine with lots of gigs of memory and 64bit architecture, and then do as BLUPEPIXY suggests.  Where resources are limited, consider a memory mapped file.  Performance can be an issue.  Usually very large matrices are implemented as sparce matrix

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic allocation is needed here. So you need 100000*100000 = 10 billion bits. That's a lot.

10,000,000,000 bits == 1,250,000,000 bytes == 1.164 gigabytes.

So a bit over a gigabyte.. It isn't impossible, but you have to be careful. The best way to do it would be to allocate it in a single array, like this:

```
uint8_t *matrix = malloc(1250000000);
if (matrix == NULL) // This will very likely fail, so be sure to handle it..
     return ENOMEM;
```

You now only have a single array. To access an element `[i][j]`, you'd do `i*10000+j`. However, since we have allocated an array of `uint8_t`, you need to extract the bits you want.

To do that, you could have accessor macros, like these:

```
// You probably want to add matrix as a param for these macros
#define index(i, j)   (i*10000+j)
#define elem(i,j)   (matrix[index(i,j)/8])
#define get(i, j)   (elem(i,j) & (1 << index(i,j)%8))
#define set(i,j,v)  (v ? elem(i,j) |= (1 << index(i,j)%8) : elem(i,j) &= ~(1 << index(i,j)%8))

set(5000, 5000, TRUE);
if (get(5000, 5000))
   doStuff();
```

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour 100k row and 100k columns is 10B total. Since he only uses bools, that is one bit per entry. 10B/8 is 1.25B. If we allocated a full byte for every bool, it would be almost 10 gigabytes, which is too much. This way it is just a bit over a gigabyte.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour Technically, I used `uint8_t` which is 8. :P I only assume that a *byte* is 8 bits, when I did the calculations.

Comment: Ahh, I missed that. My bad :P

Comment: I just noticed an error in your `elem` macro... You're missing a `]`.

Answer (score 2):

On a technical note, a *definition* is quite different to a *declaration*. I figure you're asking for a *type synonym*.

```
typedef bool matrix[100000][100000];
```

The type `matrix` is now defined as a type synonym for `bool[100000][100000]`.

```
matrix *m = malloc(sizeof *m);
```

`m` is declared to be a pointer to `matrix`, and initialised to the return value of a suitable `malloc` call.

```
static matrix s;
```

`s` is declared to be a `matrix` with static storage duration, as suggested within the comments.

This is really quite inefficient. If you don't plan on using *all* of those elements, perhaps you could try using an ordered map of some kind. I've written one you could use, called a PATRICIA trie, which you can find [here](https://github.com/Sebbyastian/patricia). If you *do* plan on using all of those elements, then you could save a lot of memory (and time, in the form of cache misses) by making use of *all* of the bits within the array, rather than typically 1/8th or worse of them, the waste being in the form of padding. This would require some slightly more complex logic.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef unsigned char matrix[100000][100000 / CHAR_BIT + (100000 % CHAR_BIT > 0)];

int matrix_get(matrix *m, size_t x, size_t y) {
    return ((*m)[x][y / CHAR_BIT] >> (y % CHAR_BIT)) & 1;
}

void matrix_set(matrix *m, size_t x, size_t y, int value) {
    (*m)[x][y / CHAR_BIT] &= ~(1U    << (y % CHAR_BIT));
    (*m)[x][y / CHAR_BIT] |=   value << (y % CHAR_BIT) ;
}

int main(void) {
    matrix *m = malloc(sizeof *m);
    memset(m, 0, sizeof *m);
    matrix_set(m, 0x1337, 0xC0DE, 1);
    printf("%d\n", matrix_get(m, 0x1337, 0xC0DE));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to do some bit masking, you can allocate `int matrix[100000][1000000/(sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT)+1]` words. Your program will be slower, but you would allocate 1/8th the amount of memory. See [How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c-c) for bit masking.

If the size of memory is too large for the stack or heap, you might consider [memory mapped IO](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Memory_002dmapped-I_002fO.html).

Comment: What is `sizeof matrix`? Have you tested that?

Comment: int 4
matrix 1215752192

Comment: That's a bit better... Now, supposing `sizeof(int)` is some odd number like 3, you might be missing a few bits...

Comment: Changed answer based on undefined behavior's comment. 8 bits per byte.

Comment: `100000/3 == 33333`... `333333/8 == 4166`... `4166+1 == 4167`... So there are 4167 `int`s in each row/column/whatever you want to call it. If we multiply that by 8, then by 3 again we should reach *at least* `100000`, but alas, you're not quite there yet :(